# Can't get text from another application (window)

Tags: c#, text, extract

I am trying to extract text from another application. This application may for now be whatever simple, I just want it to work (for now).

The code I use:

```
public static class ModApi
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageTimeout", SetLastError =     true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern uint SendMessageTimeoutText(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int countOfChars, StringBuilder text, uint flags, uint uTimeoutj, uint result);

    public static string GetText(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        var text = new StringBuilder(1024);

        if (SendMessageTimeoutText(hwnd, 0xd, 1024, text, 0x2, 5000, 0) != 0)
        {
            return text.ToString();
        }

        MessageBox.Show(text.ToString());
        return "";
    }
}
```

I call this code using:

```
IntPtr MytestHandle = new IntPtr(0x00788600);
HandleRef hrefHWndTarget = new HandleRef(null, MytestHandle);
```

where `0x00788600` is an example of one of the applications I'm running (I'm 100% sure that this is the main window handle).

I need to have the text from one textbox inside the "other" application, but when I use my code it returns an empty string every time

Suggestions?

Comment: What exactly are all of those hard-coded magic numbers supposed to do? What makes you think that the number you're using as an HWND is actually a valid window handle? (Yeah, I read *I'm 100% sure*, but because you say so doesn't make it true - what does [IsWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528(v=vs.85).aspx) say?.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see any mistakes with your code. I suggest checking whether your handle is correct or not.

However, in order to get the text of the `TextBox`, you will have to use the handle of the actual control. The MainWindowHandle will only return the form caption.

I created a dummy application "WindowsFormsApplication1" with some controls in it and used the following code to get all the texts:

```
[Flags]
internal enum SendMessageTimeoutFlags : uint
{
    SMTO_NORMAL = 0x0,
    SMTO_BLOCK = 0x1,
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x2,
    SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG = 0x8,
    SMTO_ERRORONEXIT = 0x20
}

// Specific import for WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageTimeout", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern int SendMessageTimeout(
    IntPtr hwnd,
    uint Msg,              // Use WM_GETTEXTLENGTH
    int wParam,
    int lParam,
    SendMessageTimeoutFlags flags,
    uint uTimeout,
    out int lpdwResult);

// Specific import for WM_GETTEXT
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageTimeout", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern uint SendMessageTimeoutText(
    IntPtr hWnd,
    uint Msg,              // Use WM_GETTEXT
    int countOfChars,
    StringBuilder text,
    SendMessageTimeoutFlags flags,
    uint uTImeoutj,
    out IntPtr result);

[DllImport("user32")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr window, EnumWindowProc callback, IntPtr i);

// callback to enumerate child windows
private delegate bool EnumWindowProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr parameter);

private static bool EnumChildWindowsCallback(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
{
    // this method will be called foreach child window
    // create a GCHandle from pointer
    var gcHandle = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);

    // cast pointer as list
    var list = gcHandle.Target as List<IntPtr>;

    if (list == null)
        throw new InvalidCastException("Invalid cast of GCHandle as List<IntPtr>");

    // Adds the handle to the list.
    list.Add(handle);

    return true;
}

private static IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
{
    // Create list to store child window handles.
    var result = new List<IntPtr>();

    // Allocate list handle to pass to EnumChildWindows.
    var listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);

    try
    {
        // enumerates though the children
        EnumChildWindows(parent, EnumChildWindowsCallback, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
    }
    finally
    {
        // free unmanaged list handle
        if (listHandle.IsAllocated)
            listHandle.Free();
    }

    return result;
}

internal static string GetText(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    const uint WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;
    const uint WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
    int length;
    IntPtr p;

    var result = SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0, SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5, out length);

    if (result != 1 || length <= 0)
        return string.Empty;

    var sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);

    return SendMessageTimeoutText(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, sb.Capacity, sb, SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 5, out p) != 0 ?
            sb.ToString() : 
            string.Empty;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("WindowsFormsApplication1").First();            

    Console.WriteLine(GetText(p.MainWindowHandle));    // main window handle of form, returns "Form1"
    Console.WriteLine(GetText(new IntPtr(0x70BA0)));   // actual textbox handle, used Winspector, returns "quertz"

    // iterate through dynamic handles of children
    foreach (var hwnd in GetChildWindows(p.MainWindowHandle))
        Console.WriteLine($"{hwnd}:{GetText(hwnd)}");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: You are A-A-A-A-AMAZING! Thank you so much, after juggling around with Winspector (which you wrote as a comment) it got everything to work! Thank you so much :)

Comment: This answer is a time saver. I am not sure why it has a low score

Answer (score 2):

To save a lot of code you can use the Autoit Library.

Install the nuget package called `AutoItX.Dotnet`

```
using AutoIt;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var text = AutoItX.ControlGetText("Untitled - Notepad", "", "[CLASSNN:Edit1]");

        //In your case, since you are dealing with handles, you can use:
        var windowHandle = new IntPtr(0x00788600);
        var controlHandle = new IntPtr(0x00000000);
        var text2 = AutoItX.ControlGetText(windowHandle, controlHandle);
    }
}
```